# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 : When mocking HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am getting following exception while writing test case for my code. I mocked the HttpURLConnection but still while debugging I can see that it takes values of dummy URL that I provide in my test.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://dummyURL.com
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at tcd.edu.repositoryextractor.PullObject.fetchJSONString(PullObject.java:23)
at tcd.edu.repositoryextractor.PullObjectTest.testPullObjectWithValidString(PullObjectTest.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:35)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Following is the test class

```
public class PullObjectTest {

@InjectMocks
PullObject pullObject = new PullObject();

@Mock
WrappedUrl mockedURL;

@Mock
HttpURLConnection mockedHttpConnection;

@Mock
BufferedReader mockedReader;

@Mock
InputStream mockedInputStream;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testPullObjectForNullString() {
    assertNull(pullObject.fetchJSONString(null));
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Test
public void testPullObjectWithValidString() {
    try {
        Mockito.when(mockedURL.openConnection()).thenReturn(mockedHttpConnection);
        Mockito.when(mockedHttpConnection.getInputStream()).thenReturn(mockedInputStream);

        Mockito.when(mockedReader.readLine()).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
            private int count = 1;

            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                if (count++ == 1)
                    return "This is String";
                return null;
            }
        });

        assertEquals("This is String", pullObject.fetchJSONString("http://dummyURL.com"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Following is the class I need to test

```
public class PullObject {

public String fetchJSONString(String url) {
    if (url == null)
        return null;

    StringBuffer bufferedResponse = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        WrappedUrl obj = new WrappedUrl(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        bufferedResponse = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            bufferedResponse.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bufferedResponse.toString();
}
}

class WrappedUrl {
URL obj;

WrappedUrl(String url) {
    try {
        obj = new URL(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public URLConnection openConnection() {
    URLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = obj.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}
}
```

Comment: It seems like your actually getting a real instance of HttpURLConnection.      HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();  You should try dependency injection or setting it to the mock object you create in your test.  Have you tried a break point and verifying it's a mock?

Comment: I am sort of new to Mockito. So when I do Mockito.when(mockedURL.openConnection()).thenReturn(mockedHttpConnection); does it not return mocked instance of HttpURLConnection?

Comment: I applied breakpoint but it does not mock the HttpURLConnection and I do not know why.

Comment: No...that would only tell it the response when openConnection() method is called...so the mock object is still only in your test class, not in the production code.  You'll need to set a member variable or something in the production class with the mock you created.  Let me post an example below

Comment: Thank you. That would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...I have recreated your setup for most part and have a mock now.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

public class PullObject {

    private WrappedUrl wrappedUrl;

    public void setWrappedUrl(WrappedUrl wrappedUrl) {
        this.wrappedUrl = wrappedUrl;
    }

    public String fetchJSONString(String url) {
        if (url == null)
            return null;

        StringBuffer bufferedResponse = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            wrappedUrl.setUrl(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) wrappedUrl.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;
            bufferedResponse = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                bufferedResponse.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bufferedResponse.toString();
    }
}
```

I pulled one of the classes out to it's own file:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


class WrappedUrl {
    URL obj;

    WrappedUrl(String url) {
        try {
            obj = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        try {
            obj = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public URLConnection openConnection() {
        URLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = obj.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

And here's my test:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import static junit.framework.TestCase.*;

public class PullObjectTest {

    @InjectMocks
    PullObject pullObject = new PullObject();

    @Mock
    WrappedUrl mockedURL;

    @Mock
    HttpURLConnection mockedHttpConnection;

    @Mock
    BufferedReader mockedReader;

    @Mock
    InputStream mockedInputStream;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        pullObject.setWrappedUrl(mockedURL);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPullObjectForNullString() {
        assertNull(pullObject.fetchJSONString(null));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Test
    public void testPullObjectWithValidString() {
        try {
            Mockito.when(mockedURL.openConnection()).thenReturn(mockedHttpConnection);
            Mockito.when(mockedHttpConnection.getInputStream()).thenReturn(mockedInputStream);

            Mockito.when(mockedReader.readLine()).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
                private int count = 1;

                public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    if (count++ == 1)
                        return "This is String";
                    return null;
                }
            });

            assertEquals("This is String", pullObject.fetchJSONString("http://dummyURL.com"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running into a new issue now but I'm definitely getting a mock object:

```
java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:288)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at PullObject.fetchJSONString(PullObject.java:28)
    at PullObjectTest.testPullObjectWithValidString(PullObjectTest.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147
```

)

The issue is the architecture...you are grabbing instances of the classes instead of a member variable or an injected instance.  Either way...you need to ensure the mock you create in test gets set in your production code.

Hope this helps.

[image]

***UPDATE***

Updated PullObject:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

class PullObject {

    private WrappedUrl wrappedUrl;

    private HttpURLConnection connection;

    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    PullObject(String url) {
        wrappedUrl = new WrappedUrl(url);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) wrappedUrl.openConnection();
        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void setWrappedUrl(WrappedUrl wrappedUrl) {
        this.wrappedUrl = wrappedUrl;
    }

    void setConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    void setBufferedReader(BufferedReader bufferedReader) {
        this.bufferedReader = bufferedReader;
    }

    String fetchJSONString(String url) {
        if (url == null)
            return null;

        StringBuffer bufferedResponse = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            String inputLine;
            bufferedResponse = new StringBuffer();

            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    bufferedResponse.append(inputLine);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bufferedResponse.toString();
    }
}
```

Update WrapperURL class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


class WrappedUrl {
    private URL obj;

    WrappedUrl(String url) {
        try {
            obj = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    URLConnection openConnection() {
        URLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = obj.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Updated test that passes:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import static junit.framework.TestCase.*;

public class PullObjectTest {

    private PullObject pullObject;

    @Mock
    WrappedUrl mockedURL;

    @Mock
    HttpURLConnection mockedHttpConnection;

    @Mock
    BufferedReader mockedReader;

    @Mock
    InputStream mockedInputStream;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        pullObject = new PullObject("http://dummyURL.com");
        pullObject.setWrappedUrl(mockedURL);
        pullObject.setBufferedReader(mockedReader);
        pullObject.setConnection(mockedHttpConnection);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPullObjectForNullString() {
        assertNull(pullObject.fetchJSONString(null));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Test
    public void testPullObjectWithValidString() {
        try {
            Mockito.when(mockedURL.openConnection()).thenReturn(mockedHttpConnection);
            Mockito.when(mockedHttpConnection.getInputStream()).thenReturn(mockedInputStream);

            Mockito.when(mockedReader.readLine()).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
                private int count = 1;

                public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                    if (count++ == 1)
                        return "This is String";
                    return null;
                }
            });

            assertEquals("This is String", pullObject.fetchJSONString("http://dummyURL.com"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: yes thanks...the error got removed..but the problem now is that I am not able to inject mockedBufferedReader into my class due to which it is creating new reader and giving the exception which you have shown above.

Comment: @SagarSachdeva Please look at my update...I took some liberties and re-architected it a bit to pass